# How to show a button by clicking on a button inside another UIViewController

Tags: uibutton

How to show a Button by clicking on an UIButton inside another UIViewController? 
I would want to add a button in the FirstViewController when clicking a button in the SecondViewController...
Excused my poor question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Set a boolean property in your first VC's interface and access it when the other button is pressed in second VC. Use the boolean flag to add (or show/hide) the button in first VC.

Long answer: The strategy is a little bit different if you want to "add" a button or you want to "show" a hidden button that is already there. Assuming you want to "add" a button:

1. In your FirstViewController's interface you need:

   @ property BOOL firstButtonShouldShow;

   @ property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton* firstButton;

   // and make sure you connect the outlet to the button
2. And in FirstViewController.m you need:

   -(void)viewDidLoad {

   if (firstButtonShouldShow) [firstButton setHidden:NO];

   else [firstButton setHidden:YES];

   {
3. Now in your SecondViewController.m:

   -(void)prepareForSegue ... {

   ```
   FirstViewController* firstVC = segue.destinationViewController;

   firstVC.firstButtonShouldShow = YES;
   ```

   }